# Error "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer"

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

In jQuery grid on button click I am displaying something like 28000 rows. I know some of them are suggested to define the JsonmaxLength in web config file, but it's not working for me.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What product is this - jquery? What have you done about `maxJsonLength`?

Comment: that translates into 2.8MB even for relatively small 100 byte items... Are you sure this is feasible? Why not paginate? Piping 28k rows over the Internet doesn't sound good.

Comment: Looks like this is an asp.net error, not related to jquery. Please retag appropriately.

Comment: My quetions when I am getting 28k rows from DB2 i am getting this exceptoin,, if i am trying like 6000 its doing fyn.. but more than that its giving problem.. some people are sujjested to dfine maxlength i did that but still showing excpetion while getting data..

Comment: are you using IE?  IE will limit this size to a lot less for sites not on its whitelist

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the entry in your web config?

Have you tried something like this?

```
<system.web.extensions>  
    <scripting>  
      <webServices>  
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000">    
        </jsonSerialization>    
      </webServices>   
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

more info [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805164025/http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/08/05/how-to-configure-maxjsonlength-in-asp.net-ajax-applications.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> i am displaying something like 28000 rows?

That sounds like a user interface nightmare to me.  About the *most* rows you should ever think about presenting directly to a user at one time is 500.  Anything beyond that and at best you're giving someone a false sense that they've seen a representative sample of your data.

Even paging is not a solution here unless you have a good sort.  You should really have a search interface, aggregate it into a smaller set (think charts or graphs), or make it available for download in a format the user can open in a tool to help do real analysis on it (csv, excel, etc).